# git submodule branch clone

Tags: git, git-submodules

I want to do a branch of the project including same branch in all submodules.
Then after commit & push for all subrepos & main repo.
I want to be able to clone the new branch for everything.

After I commit and everything looks fine - I try to clone.

For some reason the submodule does not point to the new branch
forcing me to switch/checkout in the submodule.

Is this the normal behavior?
Am I doing something wrong / could I do something better?
Is there a way to "clone" all submodules with branch switched?

Thank you.
David.

Comment: $ git --version
git version 2.19.0.windows.1

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

This is normal.  You'll want to write or find a little wrapper to deal with it (or hooks: see [see philb's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64740516/git-submodule-branch-clone/64741546?noredirect=1#comment114474255_64741546)).  Read on for the long explanation.

#### Submodules use *commits*, not *branches*

This is a slight overstatement, but the main thing here is that it's only *slight*.  If you start with that idea in mind, the rest of it all makes sense.

Remember what a submodule is:

- First, it *is* a Git repository, so it consists of commits.  It has branch and tag names that help Git *find* those commits, but it's really all about the commits.
- Second—and this is the part that makes it a submodule, rather than just a plain repository—it's *controlled by* some other Git repository, which Git calls the *superproject* for this submodule.

The key to understanding everything about submodules is that the superproject lists a *raw commit hash*.  The superproject Git will run:

```
git -C path/to/submodule checkout $hash
```

or equivalently:

```
git -C path/to/submodule switch --detach $hash
```

whenever you have the superproject in charge check out some commit *in* the superproject.  The `$hash` value for this command is determined by the *index* in the superproject Git repository, and the index hash value is initially that from the current commit.  So it's the current commit that controls the hash ID that the superproject forces upon the submodule.

Now, this too is too strong a claim: the superproject doesn't *always* go into the submodule and run a detached-HEAD switch / checkout command.  It does so at some particular set of times.  Precisely *when* it goes into the submodule and does this gets us into all the gory details.  But it's the way submodules are intended to work.  Declaring a branch for a submodule, with the `git submodule add -b` option for instance, **does not change this behavior.**

What you'd like to see, apparently, is:

```
git -C path/to/submodule checkout $branch
```

or:

```
git -C path/to/submodule switch $branch
```

where `$branch` is set to a branch name, that comes from somewhere.  There are no built in cases where *exactly* this occurs, but there are a few ways to make it happen.

#### So when *do* you get branch-name behavior in submodules?

What actually runs the `git checkout` inside each submodule is a `git submodule update` command.  (See sidebar below.)  If you consult [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), you will see that `git submodule update` has a huge number of options.  There is no combination of options that makes `git submodule update` run the command you want.

Git will do an automatic submodule update (see sidebar again) on `git checkout` in the superproject *if* you have set the recursion option for that checkout.  That is, `git checkout --recurse-submodules` will do it, as will plain `git checkout` if you've set `submodule.recurse` to `true` in your configuration.  An explicit `git checkout --no-recurse-submodules` will inhibit Git's automatic update.

(Note that `git clone` itself ends by running an internal `git checkout` command, unless you use `git clone --no-checkout`.  That checkout will recurse, or not recurse, based on the `--recurse-submodules` flag passed to `git clone`, or again the configuration you've set.)

If you didn't have `git checkout` do an automatic update, you would normally manually run *your own* `git submodule update` command now.  You can choose *not* to run `git submodule update`, or to run it but follow it up with a:

```
git -C path/to/submodule switch $branch
```

command.  None of this is automatic, of course.

#### Sidebar: `git checkout` does not use `git submodule update`

The *user-facing* command for updating submodules is `git submodule update`.  But `git checkout` itself doesn't literally run `git submodule update`: instead, it has hardcoded into it the behavior of `git submodule update --checkout`.  This is, at least currently, in [`entry.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7f7ebe054af6d831b999d6c2241b9227c4e4e08d/entry.c#L472-L488), which notices that the gitlink hash ID changed and calls [`submodule_move_head` in `submodule.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7f7ebe054af6d831b999d6c2241b9227c4e4e08d/submodule.c#L1888-L2009), which currently uses an invocation of `git read-tree`, passing it a raw hash ID.  So it can't use the desired commands.

#### Using `git submodule update`

You can select a submodule update mode:

> The "updating" can be done in several ways depending on command
> line options and the value of `submodule.<name>.update` configuration
> variable. The command line option takes precedence over the configuration
> variable. If neither is given, a `checkout` is performed. ...
>
> `checkout`
>     the commit recorded in the superproject will be
> checked out ...

This is the default, and is what you are seeing.

> `rebase`
>     the current branch of the submodule will
> be rebased onto the commit recorded in the superproject.

This is closer to what you want, but isn't what you want at all, plus there's a bootstrap issue: what exactly *is* the current branch of the submodule?

> `merge`
>     the commit recorded in the superproject will
> be merged into the current branch in the submodule.

That's also not what you want, and has the same question to resolve.

> The following `update` procedures are only available via the `submodule.<name>.update` configuration variable:
>
> **custom command**
>     arbitrary shell command that takes a single
> argument (the sha1 of the commit recorded in the superproject) is
> executed. When `submodule.<name>.update` is set to **!command**,
> the remainder after the exclamation mark is the custom command.

This is the only one of the update commands that *could* do what you want.  You can set a custom command that will do your desired `git checkout` or `git switch`.  Note that the branch name is not provided to you; you will have to fish it out from somewhere.  This is overly difficult (I think); read on, or jump to the conclusion section to see what I think is the right way to do it.

> `none`
>     the submodule is not updated

(I included this for completeness, but obviously doesn't do what you want.)

But wait: there is one more option!  It's not described here, for some reason; it's left down in the **OPTIONS** section.  It is the `--remote` option:

> `--remote`
>     This option is only valid for the update command.
> Instead of using the superproject’s recorded SHA-1 to update the
> submodule, use the status of the submodule’s remote-tracking branch.
> The remote used is branch’s remote (`branch.<name>.remote`),
> defaulting to `origin`. The remote branch used defaults to the remote
> `HEAD`, but the branch name may be overridden by setting the
> `submodule.<name>.branch` option in either `.gitmodules` or `.git/config`
> (with `.git/config` taking precedence).
>
> This works for any of the supported update procedures (`--checkout`,
> `--rebase`, etc.). The only change is the source of the target SHA-1.
> For example, `submodule update --remote --merge` will merge upstream
> submodule changes into the submodules, while `submodule update --merge`
> will merge superproject gitlink changes into the submodules.
>
> In order to ensure a current tracking branch state, `update --remote`
> fetches the submodule’s remote repository before calculating the SHA-1.
> If you don’t want to fetch, you should use
> `submodule update --remote --no-fetch`.

This does *almost* what you want.  There are two problems:

- It runs `git -C path/to/submodule fetch`, then `git -C path/to/submodule rev-parse origin/$branch`, then runs `git -C path/to/submodule switch --detach $hash` where `$hash` is the result of the `rev-parse` step.  (It's a little silly that it uses three commands to achieve this when two, `fetch` and `switch --detach`, would suffice: the switch can do the rev-parse internally.  But this is a side effect of the way it's coded.)

  The drawback here is the extra `fetch` and the use of `origin/$branch`.  You can stop the fetch with `--no-fetch`, although it's probably harmless and maybe sometimes desirable.  The use of `origin/$branch` is also probably harmless: if you've just cloned the submodule repository, `$branch` may not even *exist*, and the result is always going to be a detached HEAD because submodules are always detached HEADs, so `origin/$branch` should be fine.
- The bigger drawback is that you literally *can't* get `--remote` specified without manually running a `git submodule update` in the first place.  And, in any case, you're *still* left on a detached HEAD in the submodule!

#### Conclusion

> Is there a way to "clone" all submodules with branch switched?

No.  However, if you're willing to use something other than Git—e.g., to use a wrapper that *runs* Git—it's easy enough.  For your case, a trivial wrapper that runs `git clone` followed by `git submodule update --init` followed by `git submodule foreach --recursive` with a shell function (that you provide) that invokes the `git switch` command would do the job.  Using `git submodule foreach` is superior (I think) to trying to use a custom update command, as you'll gain easy access to the superproject and submodule parts so that you can fish out a branch name from the superproject's settings.

You can also use `git clone` followed by `git submodule update --checkout --remote` to get to the right *hash ID*, if that's good enough.

Comment: `git checkout --recurse-submodules` exists since Git 2.13... I know this won't put you on a branch in the submodules, but I think it should at least be mentioned.

Comment: Also, you write "The git submodule update command is run automatically on git checkout in the superproject if you have set the recursion option for that checkout." That is not technically true, `git submodule update` is not invoked by checkout/reset/read-tree/switch/restore when used with `--recurse-submodules`. So it's not exactly the same semantics. The code that recurses in submodule is in `unpack-trees.c`.

Comment: In my first comment I meant "mentioned explicitely".

Comment: @philb: the `--recurse-submodules` command line option is mainly what I was thinking of, but I thought setting `submodule.recurse` to `true` also did it. I'll double check though.

Comment: `submodule.recurse` is what exists. It activates `--recurse-submodules` for all commands that understand that flag, except `clone` and `ls-files`. See [the doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-submodulerecurse). Only fetch and push have their own individual config.

Comment: @philb: I've updated it for accuracy, and mentioned the `--recurse-submodules` options.

Comment: great! For completeness, I think mentioning Git hooks as a way to do what the OP wants to do would be great. A combination of `post-merge`, `post-checkout` and `post-rewrite` should cover most cases.

Comment: @philb: Hm, hooks are not a bad idea - but note that they won't exist in a fresh clone (unless you clone with a personal template that install them, which I think is possible).

Comment: Yes you are right. At $DAYJOB I keep the hooks in a `script/githooks` folder and use a script `script/setup` (mentioned in the "Getting started" instruction of my READMEs) to copy them to the correct location.